# Пример Entity Framework provider версии 6

Tags: c#, entity-framework

Где бы посмотреть примерчик скелета по вызовам Entity Framework provider версии 6, на мсдн нашел только для 5 версии и ниже, сырцы EFSQLProvider неподьемные по объему, и запутанные весьма, буду благодарен за ссылку или описание API вызовов.

Comment: [это?](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/ef6/fundamentals/providers/provider-model)

Comment: @tym32167, да оно :) АПИ вызовов прада не нашел с ходу, но есть чего почитать, как же я Гуглом то этого не нашел, спасибо.

Comment: ну я просто ваш [вопрос погуглил](https://www.google.com/search?q=Entity+Framework+provider+версии+6&oq=Entity+Framework+provider+версии+6) и первую ссылку взял